# Why does this simple grid layout break? (Debugging some basic HTML/CSS)

Tags: wordpress, css-float, thumbnails, html

The following page is a thumbnail gallery for a wordpress portfolio site:

http://rosspw.com/snippets/

**The issue I'm trying to address is to understand why the three column gallery grid layout is broken** -- it displays the first three thumbnails, then breaks the grid layout.

The gallery grid is created with the following wordpress/php code:

```
<div id="project-thumbs">       
<?php
                    query_posts( array(
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,                     
                        'posts_per_page' => 24,
                        'post_type' => array('snippet')
                        )); ?>                              
                    <?php  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="project-box one-third float-left">      
                            <?php get_template_part( 'part-project-thumb'); ?>
                        </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>      
        </div>
```

Also, the CSS styling I'm using for "project-thumbs" is as follows:

```
#project-thumbs {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
min-height: 625px;
padding-top: 35px;
```

}

Can you help me understand why the grid layout breaks after six thumbnails? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a height to your .project-box class like so:

```
.project-box { height: 250px; }
```

Your floated elements were varying in height, thus the float was broken.

Comment: I knew the answer was going to be embarassingly simple. Thank you @Matthew Blancarte!!  I'm new to StackOverflow, so if there's a better way to thank you for your help and increase your rept points, let me know.

Comment: Excellent. Happy to help! A simple upvote and accepting my answer is thanks enough. :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Awesome.. I was just writing a question with this same issue and this was a suggested post -- solved my issue and increased my understanding of foundation!

Comment: @HC_ Sweet! Glad I could help!